# Polymer custom element tag appearing in the DOM

Tags: html, css, polymer, polymer-1.0

I've just started learning about Polymer custom elements.

I've created a very simple custom element, the usage of which is as follows:

```
<my_custom_element></my_custom_element>
```

The template for the custom element is:

```
 <template>
   <span>Hello</span>
 </template>
```

If I inspect the DOM using Chrome Dev tools, I notice that `my_custom_element` tag appears in the DOM. I wasn't expecting this. I was expecting that this tag would be replaced by the template content. What does `my_custom_element` represent in its own right?

I also read that `:host` can be used to style a custom element internally from within its definition and it's used to style host element itself. But again I don't understand what it means to style the host element in its own right. Isn't the host element defined by its template content?

Comment: i don't know anything about polymer, but it's possible that it's creating a custom xmlns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web components model does not use `<my-custom-element>` as a placeholder, but as an actual and real HTML element with complex behaviors and its own contents.

Comment: But from a content perspective, isn't a custom element defined by its template content (and perhaps any other dynamic changes made to that content)? I'm still not fully grasping the concept of being able to, say, apply a style to the custom element itself. Unless, say, Polymer wraps up the template content in, say, a div tag, and applies the style to the div?

Comment: Polymer doesn't "wrap" your custom element, it simply does not remove it from the page.  When you put `<my-element>` on a page, it's really and truly there.  Polymer gives it behaviors that can "fill in" that element with things, but it's there to stay.  That means you can also style that element externally, with a css `my-element {}` selector, give it classes, IDs, etc.